# Pandas and Python Dataframes and Conditional Shift Function

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

Is there a conditional "shift" parameter in data frames?

For example,

Assume I own a used car lot and I have data as follows

```
SaleDate    Car
12/1/2016   Wrangler
12/2/2016   Camry
12/3/2016   Wrangler
12/7/2016   Prius
12/10/2016  Prius
12/12/2016  Wrangler
```

I want to find two things out from this list -

1) For each sale, when was the last day that a car was sold?  This is simple in Pandas, just a simple shift as follows

```
df['PriorSaleDate'] = df['SaleDate'].shift()
```

2) For each sale, when was the prior date that the same type of car was sold?  So, for example, the Wrangler sale on 12/3 would point two rows back to 12/1 (the last time the "car" value in row 3 was equal to the "car" value in a prior row).

For the Wrangler sold on 12/12, I would want the value of 12/3

Is there a conditional shift parameter that would allow me to get the row there the value df['Car'] equals the value of df['Car']  in that row?

Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `groupby` and `shift()`:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

text = """SaleDate    Car
12/1/2016   Wrangler
12/2/2016   Camry
12/3/2016   Wrangler
12/7/2016   Prius
12/10/2016  Prius
12/12/2016  Wrangler"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0])
df["lastSaleDate"] = df.groupby("Car").SaleDate.shift()
```

the output:

```
    SaleDate       Car lastSaleDate
0 2016-12-01  Wrangler          NaT
1 2016-12-02     Camry          NaT
2 2016-12-03  Wrangler   2016-12-01
3 2016-12-07     Prius          NaT
4 2016-12-10     Prius   2016-12-07
5 2016-12-12  Wrangler   2016-12-03
```

Comment: I like that solution, but is there any way to be able to retain the last sale date based on the prior row or would I need to make it a two step process (groupby with shift and then df['PriorSaleDate'] = df['SaleDate'].shift())? thanks!

Comment: HYRY's answer seems to do exactly what you want.  You just need to make two asignments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm basically copying HYRY's answer and modifying it slightly.  If you like this solution.  Choose HYRY's answer as your answer.

```
from StringIO import StringIO  # this is what I needed to do
import pandas as pd

text = """SaleDate    Car
12/1/2016   Wrangler
12/2/2016   Camry
12/3/2016   Wrangler
12/7/2016   Prius
12/10/2016  Prius
12/12/2016  Wrangler"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, parse_dates=[0])

# what you already did
df['PriorSaleDate'] = df['SaleDate'].shift()

# what HYRY did
df["CarSpecificPriorSaleDate"] = df.groupby("Car").SaleDate.shift()
```

#### Looks like

```
Out[34]:
    SaleDate       Car PriorSaleDate CarSpecificPriorSaleDate
0 2016-12-01  Wrangler           NaT                      NaT
1 2016-12-02     Camry    2016-12-01                      NaT
2 2016-12-03  Wrangler    2016-12-02               2016-12-01
3 2016-12-07     Prius    2016-12-03                      NaT
4 2016-12-10     Prius    2016-12-07               2016-12-07
5 2016-12-12  Wrangler    2016-12-10               2016-12-03
```