# Conditional Shift until Previous Category

Tags: python, pandas

I want to pick up a question asked previously by someone else:
[Pandas and Python Dataframes and Conditional Shift Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36770814/pandas-and-python-dataframes-and-conditional-shift-function)
There is asked how to get the sales date of the previous car of the same type in pandas, the user was asking for a condition shift function. The answer though was a groupby car and a shift, which solves the problem.
Now I want to calculate e.g. the sales date of a car of a different (e.g. lexicographically previous) type. So a conditioal shift function which shifts until a condition (car type changed) would solve the problem. How would one do that? Thanks!

Edit:

```
An example from my part, my dataframe is:
  A  B     Previous   MyPrevious
0 0  1.5   nan        nan
1 0  2     1.5        nan
2 0  2.5   2          nan
3 1  3.7   nan        2.5
4 1  4     3.7        2.5
5 2  4.2   nan        4
```

It has already been sorted by A and B. The previous asker wanted to know "what is the previous value of column B where A is of the same type". So as you can see in row 0 there is no previous row thus nan, in row 1 the previous row also has A = 0 =>  Previous = 1.5 and so on. I now want "the previous value of column B where A is smaller by 1". Meaning for all rows with A = 0 we dont have any rows where A is -1 thus nan. For all rows with A = 1 we take the last row with A = 0, here B is 2.5. I hope this explains it.

Comment: Can you give an example? I find it a bit hard to understand what exactly you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use `groupby` and `shift` but in a slightly different way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,0,0,1,1,2], 'B':[1.5,2,2.5,3.7,4,4.2]})
grouped = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).last().shift().B
grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
pd.merge(df, grouped, left_on='A', right_index=True)
```

Outputs:

```
   A  B_x  B_y
0  0  1.5  NaN
1  0  2.0  NaN
2  0  2.5  NaN
3  1  3.7  2.5
4  1  4.0  2.5
5  2  4.2  4.0
```

Note: This does assume that A contains all consecutive numbers from 0 to `max(df.A)`

---

Edit: Difference and changed third value of B to 1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], 'B': [1.5, 2, 2.5, 1, 4, 4.2]})
grouped = df.groupby('A', as_index=False).min().shift().B
grouped = pd.DataFrame(grouped)
merged = pd.merge(df, grouped, left_on='A', right_index=True)
print(np.abs(merged.B_x - merged.B_y))
```

outputs:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.5
4    2.5
5    3.2
dtype: float64
```

---

Edit 2:

This took me a while but I think it works now. Don't think it's the *best* solution, but it works ;)

```
def f(x):
    if x.B_y != x.B_y:  # Check if value is NaN
        return np.nan
    return x.B_x - min(x.B_y, key=lambda v: abs(v - x.B_x))

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], 'B': [1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 4, 4.2]})
a = pd.DataFrame(df.groupby('A').B.apply(list).shift())
result = pd.merge(df, a, left_on='A', right_index=True).apply(f, axis=1)
print(result)
```

outputs:

```
0    NaN
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    0.5
4    1.5
5    0.2
dtype: float64
```

Now in `a` the lists of the previous group are stored, which can then be merged in the dataframe on the index. Then function `f(x)` is applied on all rows which finds the smallest distance between `x.B_x` and the values of `x.B_y` (the list).

Comment: great, thanks! Sorry, it's probably off-topic but for my concreate application scenario I do not need the last element, but I want the one with the smallest distance. So the output should be [Nan, Nan, Nan, 1.2, 1.5, 0.2].

Comment: `merged.B_x - merged.B_y` returns a series with the difference and `(merged.B_x - merged.B_y).min()` the smallest value of those.

Comment: This is not what I want and just works as here B is already ascending. Set df.loc[3, 'B'] = 1. Then your differences both give -1.5. However, what I want is the minmal distance from the value of B in row 3 to any row with A = 0, which is 0.5.

Comment: This is actually why I also thought of a "conditional shift". I would then sort only by B and shift as long back as I find a row with an A matching my condition.

Comment: unfortunately also not. You are calculating the mininum of a group with common A value and then substract value of column B. I however want to compute for each row x the minimum of x.B - y.B, where y is a row for which y.A + 1 = x.A. So in the last row of your example the result is wrong e.g. it should be 0.2 (4.2 - 4, not 4.2 - 1). Am I explaining this properly?

Comment: Don't you mean that it should be `4.2 - 2.5`?

Comment: I dont think so, because for Row 5 A = 2 and for Row 3 and 4 A = 1. 2.5 is from Row 0 - 2  where A = 0. Or am I missing sth?

Comment: So you want the biggest B from the previous A group and subtract it from the smallest B from the current A group. So for `A=1` that's `3.7 - 2.5 = 1.2`, and for `A=2` that's `4.2 - 4 = 0.2` Where does the `1.5` come from?

Comment: No, I do not want that. I dont want the smallest / biggest value of a group. For every row I want to find that value of the "previous" group which minimizes the difference to the curernt value. So  e.g. for row 3 we consider all rows with A = 0, as in row 3 we have A = 1. The value of B in row 3 is: 3.7. Then the difference is minimized by 3.7 - 2.5. For row 4 the difference is mininized also by 4.0 - 2.5. For row 5 we consider all rows with A = 1, the difference there is minimized by 4.2 - 4.

Comment: (in the comments I wrote we set the value of B in row 3 to 1, lets forget that and stick with the original numbers)